# Execute array of arrays of promises and run validation callbacks after each series sequentially

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I'm struggling with making an array of arrays of promises work. The idea behind this is the following:

**Schedule** is an array of following objects:

```
[   
    { priority: 0, actions: [Promise, Promise, Promise, ...] },
    { priority: 1, actions: [Promise, Promise, Promise, ...] }
    ...
]
```

The promises are AJAX calls (in my example i mock them with fake promises that resolve after random timeout).

The schedule then is sorted by priority and its actions are executed. After The validation callbacks for the next series of actions should run **only** after **all** callbacks for the current series return `true`. If any Promise is rejected or validation fails on results, the execution should stop. In other words, I need it to work in following scenario:

> 1. progressBar.activate() - blue color.
> 2. All Promises from all series are launched asynchronously.
> 3. When results for priority 0 Promises arrive, validate them asynchronously. Do not validate results from following series yet.
>
>    - Any validation fails? Any priority 0 promises are rejected?
>
>      - YES: progressBar.error() - red color; return immediately.
>    - ALL validation for priority 0 Promises is OK?
>
>      - YES: Go to next step.
> 4. Validate results for priority 1 Promises.
>
>    - ...
>    - ...
> 5. Validate results for priority 2 Promises.
>
>    - ...
>    - ...
> 6. All done, progressBar.deactivate() - orange color.

But I can't make it run in sequence - the results from all series are validated upon arrival, in random order! I guess I can't chain the calls properly in my `syncRun()` method. And progressBar is deactivated asynchronously as well before the process is finished:

```
var syncRun = function (schedule) {
    var tasks = sortSchedule(schedule);
    progressBar.activate();
    var chain = $.Deferred().resolve();
    tasks.forEach(function (step) {
        // increase the total empty width of progressBar
        progressBar.totalProgress += step.length;
        // chain the next series of promises
        chain = chain.then(function () {
                return Promise.all(step);
            }
        );
    });
    // chain the final action: deactivate progressBar
    chain = chain.then(function () {
        progressBar.deactivate();
    }, function () {});
};
```

Any advice is appreciated. Here's the full code:

```js
var progressBar = {
  activate: function() {
    $('#progress-bar').addClass('active');
  },
  deactivate: function() {
    $('#progress-bar').removeClass('active');
  },
  error: function() {
    $('#progress-bar').addClass('error');
  },
  current: 0,
  total: 0,
  setWidth: function() {
    var widthPercent = 0;
    if (this.total !== 0) {
      widthPercent = this.current / this.total * 100 + '%';
    }
    $('#progress-bar').css('width', widthPercent);
  },
  get totalProgress() {
    return this.total;
  },
  set totalProgress(value) {
    this.total = value;
    this.setWidth();
  },
  get currentProgress() {
    return this.current;
  },
  set currentProgress(value) {
    this.current = value;
    this.setWidth();
  }
};

var logger = function(message) {
  $('<p></p>').text(message).appendTo($('#logger'));
};

var resolveLimit = 6;
var validatorLimit = 6;

var fakeAjax = function(id) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      if (id <= resolveLimit) {
        resolve(id);
      } else {
        reject(id);
      }
    }, (Math.random() * 5 | 0) * 1000);
  });
};

var action = function(request, callback) {
  request.then(function(result) {
    progressBar.currentProgress++;
    var isValid = callback(result);
    if (!isValid) {
      throw 'Rejected ' + result;
    }
  });
};

var validator = function(result) {
  if (result <= validatorLimit) {
    logger('Series #' + result + ' parsed');
    return true;
  } else {
    logger('Series #' + result + ' rejected');
    progressBar.error();
    return false;
  }
};

// Generate an array of action objects of specified length
var guid = 0;
var generateActions = function(count) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    result.push(
      action(fakeAjax(guid), validator)
    );
  }
  guid++;
  return result;
};


var sortSchedule = function(schedule) {
  var tasks = [];
  schedule.forEach(function(step) {
    if (!tasks[step.priority]) {
      tasks[step.priority] = [];
    }
    tasks[step.priority] = tasks[step.priority].concat(step.actions);
  });
  return tasks.sort(function(a, b) {
    return tasks[b] - tasks[a];
  });
};

var syncRun = function(schedule) {
  var tasks = sortSchedule(schedule);
  progressBar.activate();
  var chain = $.Deferred().resolve();
  tasks.forEach(function(step) {
    // increase the total empty width of progressBar
    progressBar.totalProgress += step.length;
    // chain the next series of promises
    chain = chain.then(function() {
      return Promise.all(step);
    });
  });
  // chain the final action: deactivate progressBar
  chain = chain.then(function() {
    progressBar.deactivate();
  }, function() {});
};

var schedule = [{
    priority: 0,
    actions: generateActions(6)
  },
  {
    priority: 1,
    actions: generateActions(5)
  },
  {
    priority: 2,
    actions: generateActions(4)
  },
  {
    priority: 3,
    actions: generateActions(3)
  },
  {
    priority: 4,
    actions: generateActions(2)
  },
  {
    priority: 5,
    actions: generateActions(1)
  }
];

syncRun(schedule);
```

```css
.progress-bar-container {
  border: #999999 1px solid;
  width: 90%;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

@keyframes blinker {
  50% {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
}

.progress-bar {
  background-color: #FF9933;
  height: 4px;
  animation: blinker 1s linear infinite;
  width: 100%;
}

.active {
  background-color: #0099FF;
}

.error {
  background-color: #FF0000 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="progress-bar-container">
  <div id="progress-bar" class="progress-bar"></div>
</div>
<div id="logger">
</div>
```

Comment: It appears that you are starting all your async operations at the same time so they will all run in parallel and thus finish in random order.  If you want priority 1 actions to not start until priority 0 actions have completed, then you need to NOT start your priority 1 actions immediately, but rather wait until a `Promise.all()` of the priority 0 promise array has resolved.

Comment: A promise is a _value_ not an action - you need to use functions that return promises rather than just promises.

Comment: Why are you using `$.Deferred`? Why not just use a regular `Promise`, considering that you use it elsewhere in the code?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I'm not entirely sure anymore if this is a good solution, but in case any value can be derived from it, I threw together a class that takes a promise in the constructor, and when forces a sequence of promises that wait on the resolution of each before eventually returning the accumulated results:

```
class ChainRequest {
  constructor(promise) {
    this.promise = promise;
    this.nextPromise = null;
  }

  appendNextPromise (nextPromise) {
    this.nextPromise = nextPromise;
  }

  execute (prevResults) {
    this.results = prevResults;
    return this.promise()
    .then(result => {
      this.results.push(result);
      if (this.nextPromise !== null) {
        return this.nextPromise.execute(this.results);
      }
      else {
        return Promise.resolve(this.results);
      }
    });
  }
}

let chainPromises = [promise1, promise2, promise3...];

let currentPromise = new ChainRequest(promise1);
let headPromise = currentPromise;

for (let i = 1; i < chainPromises.length; i++) {
  let nextPromise = new ChainRequest(chainPromises[i));
  currentPromise.appendNextPromise(nextPromise);
  currentPromise = nextPromise;
}

return headPromise
.then(results => {
  console.log(results);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, change your schedule so that it lists the actions rather than invoke them immediately:

```
var schedule = [{
    priority: 0,
    actions: 6 // instead of generateActions(6)
  },
  {
    priority: 1,
    actions: 5
  },
  {
    priority: 2,
    actions: 4
  },
  {
    priority: 3,
    actions: 3
  },
  {
    priority: 4,
    actions: 2
  },
  {
    priority: 5,
    actions: 1
  }
];
```

then invoke them where you actually want to do this:

```
var chain = Promise.resolve(); // <- No need to use $.Deferred here
tasks.forEach(function(stepLength) {
  // increase the total empty width of progressBar
  progressBar.totalProgress += stepLength;
  // chain the next series of promises
  chain = chain.then(function() {
    return Promise.all(generateActions(stepLength));
  });
});
```